# SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getCredentials() returns null after authentication

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have created a simple spring web mvc app and I have one problem. After authentication I try to get an authentication  object and for some reason it's credentials is null.

[image]

In this project I have a custom AuthenticationProvider which looks like this:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private RoleService roleService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        roleService.AddStandardRolesIfNeeded();
        userService.AddUserWithAdminRoleIfNotExists("a"); 
    }


    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {


        Object credentials = authentication.getCredentials();
        if(!(credentials instanceof String)) {
            return null;
        }

        String username = authentication.getName();
        String password = credentials.toString(); //password isn't null here


        User user = userService.findByUsernameAndPassword(username, password);


        if(user == null) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Authentication failed for " + username);
        }


        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Role role : user.getRoles()) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
        }

        Authentication auth = new 
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, authorities);


        return auth;
    }

    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }

}
```

I am interested in if it is intentionally done in spring security or I am missing something.

Comment: Why are you searching by username and password? You should search by username only.

Comment: and then comparing passwords in authenticate() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by passing user object to `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` constructor instead of username in place of principal.

I changed this:

```
Authentication auth = new 
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, authorities);
```

to this:

```
Authentication auth = new 
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, password, authorities);
```

And in controller I get the user so:

```
User user = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

Comment: Your explanation gave the idea that I could pass anything in `Principal` which happens to be Object datatype. Kudos.

Answer (score 12):

Because the credentials will be deleted after authentication is successful, you must add `eraseCredentials(false)` to `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` configuration. Like the code bellow:

```
@Autowired
private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthProvider;

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthProvider).eraseCredentials(false);
}
```

This is late, but I think this is the correct answer according to the question.

Comment: I have tried this several times with this config, its not working for me, getCredentials() returns null

Comment: Can you please elaborate on `customAuthProvider`? What type of object is that? What should it implement/extend?

Comment: `customAuthProvider` is the object of `CustomAuthenticationProvider` that mentioned in the question. I have updated in the answer.

Comment: Note - this feels bad, to me: credentials should be erased after they're verified, so a vulnerability (like Heartbleed) can't leak the plaintext passwords of all logged-in users.  Better would be to verify a session token - but I don't know how to properly do that, yet; it's why I'm on SO atm.